# Building an Alexa Skill that count words

Tags: counter, cpu-word, alexa-skills-kit

I'm totally new with Alexa Skills. Is there any way to keep an Skill hearing and counting words for an unlimited time? I want to keep track of every spoken word during a day to make a report at night. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to listen to the word and store it somewhere? 
For this, you can use DynamoDB and also store the count there too.

Comment: No you can't do this. Your skill is only active for a certain amount of time after a user interacts with it. If they don't respond it closes. This is a privacy issue

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. Extending the the session timeout duration is not a supported feature of Alexa Skills Kit. There is unfortunately no recommended workaround for latency issues, as response times exceeding 8 seconds aren't supported.